# Lazy-loading collections with restrictions in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have two simple entities with one-to-many relationship:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Let's imagine, that there could be a lot of Orders for a particular Customer, and I want to see only last-month-orders.

Can I do this somehow if Orders property is lazy-loaded?
I want something like:

```
var orders = customer.Orders.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)).ToList();
```

but now nHibernate requests all the Orders on this line (`SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customerId='{0}'`), and linq-restrictions are applied on the loaded data, but I want it to be applied to SQL (`SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customerId='{0}' AND date > '2011-07-31'`).

Is this achievable with nHibernate? Can Entity Framework do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this achievable with nHibernate? Can Entity Framework do this?

Unfortunately no. NHibernate and EF cannot handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try NHibernate 3, linq support there is much better than in 2nd version. Otherwise you can make request using criterions syntax.

Comment: I do use 3rd version. I can use criterions when doing request over the Session, but the question is about doing this with lazy-loaded collections.